# How to build a query which matches one of the phrases in Spring Elasticsearch repository

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I would like to know if and how is possible to create a query which matches one of the keyword phrases and does not contain any of the stop word phrases. For example:

```
List<String> keywords = Arrays.asList("one keyword", "another one");
List<String> stopWords = Arrays.asList("dismiss this");

Page<Result> results = elRepository.findByKeywordsAndStepwords(
                                keywords, stopwords, new PageRequest(0, 12));
```

This should match documents containing one of the exact phrases ("one keyword" or "another one") and no stop word phrases ("dismiss this"). Note that if a document contains only terms which are contained in phrases (eg. "another"), it should not return the given document as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long research, this was the only way I could achieve my goal. Hope it will help someone:

```
BoolQueryBuilder keywordBuilder = boolQuery();
keywords.forEach(k -> keywordBuilder.should(matchPhraseQuery("text", k)));

BoolQueryBuilder stopWordBuilder = boolQuery();
stopWords.forEach(s -> stopWordBuilder.should(matchPhraseQuery("text", s)));

BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = boolQuery()
        .must(keywordBuilder)
        .mustNot(stopWordBuilder);          

Page<Result> results= elRepository.search(queryBuilder, pageable);
```